# DatabaseError: 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '2015-04-06 20:48:33.418000'.csv (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, csv, wamp, mysql-connector-python

I am designing an application in Python and trying to write to a CSV file, but I am getting this error:

> DatabaseError: 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '2015-04-06 20:48:33.418000'.csv (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

The Code:

```
def generate_report(self):
        conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='',host='localhost',database='mydatabase')     
        exe2 = conn.cursor()
        exe2.execute("""SELECT tbl_site.Site_name, State_Code, Country_Code,Street_Address, instrum_start_date, instrum_end_date, Comment INTO OUTFILE  %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'FROM tbl_site JOIN tbl_site_monit_invent ON site_id = tbl_Site_site_id """, (str(datetime.datetime.now()),))
```

I can run this code without any errors on a Mac, but I need it to work on Windows.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Really to little information....

Comment: Please see for the edited code above. Its a simple out-file generator in csv but its giving a permission error.

Comment: I've edited your question to include the error in the question, and removed a lot of unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply permission error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I was accessing a remote db and it didn't worked. Waited for response from long time but no body responded. Even flagged the post and then I got Workbench installed on my own system and got it working. Now its working fine with MySQL workbench so I posted it that its problem with permission errors. How is it not the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simple really. A colon character is not a valid character in a filename on Windows. It's not allowed.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The colon character is in the list of "reserved characters", along with several others. (NOTE: One use of the colon character is as a separator for an Alternate Data Stream on NTFS. Ref: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx

---

**Followup**

The question has been significantly edited since my previous answer was provided. Some notes:

I'm not very familiar with running MySQL on Windows OS.  Most of my work with MySQL server is on Linux.

The `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement will cause the MySQL server to attempt to write a file on the server host.

The MySQL user (the user logged in to MySQL) must have the `FILE` privilege in order to use the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement.

Also, the OS account that is running MySQL server must have OS permissions to write a file to the specified directory, and the file to be written must not already exist. Also, the filename must conform to the naming rules for filenames on OS filesystem.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html

For debugging this type of issue, I strongly recommend you echo out the actual SQL text that is going to be sent to the MySQL server. And then take that SQL text and run it from a different client, like the mysql command line client.

For debugging a privileges issues, you can use a much simpler statement. Test writing a file to a directory that is known to exist, that is known the mysql server has permissions to write files to, and with a filename that does not exist and that conforms to the rules for the OS and filesystem.

For example, on a normal Linux box, we could test with something like this:

```
mysql> SELECT 'bar' AS foo INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mysql_foo.csv'
```

Before we run that, we can easily verify that the `/tmp` directory exists, that it is writable by the OS account that is running the mysql server, and that the filename conforms to the rules for the filesystem, and that the filename doesn't exist, e.g.

```
$ su - mysql
$ ls -l /tmp/mysql_foo.csv
$ echo "foo" >/tmp/mysql_foo.csv
$ cat /tmp/mysql_foo.csv
$ rm /tmp/mysql_foo.csv
$ ls -l /tmp/mysql_foo.csv
```

Once we get over that hurdle, we can move on to testing writing a file to a different directory, a file with a more more complex filename. Once we get that plumbing working, we can work on getting actual data, into a usable csv format.

The original question seems to indicate that the MySQL server is running on Windows OS, and it seems to indicate that the filename attempting to be written contains semicolon characters. Windows does not allow semicolon as part a filename.

Comment: i've checked above solution but the problem does not relate to this. Please advise